# Reload combobox on parent page on closing Radwindow

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, telerik, radwindow

I am having textbox ,combobox & button controls in an aspx page.To add a new value in the combobox,I am using a button.Onclick of this 
 Button ,a **radwindow** opens which add/update some records.On closing the **radwindow**,I need to reflect those records in the parent page combobox.
For this,I have used `onclientclose` property of **radwindow**  with `window.location.reload();`.If the user has entered some data in other controls before clicking the **radwindow** button,then all data will be lost.I just need to reload the combobox on closing the **radwindow**.
Please suggest your ideas.
My code is as below:

```
<telerik:RadWindow ID="NationalityDialog" Title="Nationality Data" runat="server" Behaviors="Close" Height="550px" Width="450px" Left="150px" OnClientClose="NationClientClose" />

function NationClientClose(sender, args)
{
     window.location.reload();
     //window.location.href = window.location.href; 
}
```

Thanks,
Soumya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your suggestions.I have done that with the ajaxRequest.Anyone facing the same issue,please look in the below link http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/refresh-radgrid-on-close-of-radwindow.aspx .

Please suggest me your ideas on the below issue with radwindow.Radwindow has a grid,on which user add/edit records.user may go to the 5th page and edit a record and and "Update successfull message is shown".Now the user close the radwindow and on again opening the radwindow,the message is still there and the Grid is on 5th page.How can I show the Radwindow with Grid on first page and no messages on opening radwindow.

Thanks,
Soumya

Answer (score 1):

onclientclose , use `__doPostBack` javascript function which is part of every asp.net page to reload your web page

```
 function OnClientClose(radWindow) { 
    __doPostBack(event_target, radWindow.argument); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use RadAjaxManager and it's client side events ajaxRequest or ajaxRequestWithTarget

[here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-radajaxmanager-client-object.html) is example of it.

with this event you can rebind your dropdown without causing postback.